# Update the Nginx CR status using the status writer with the names of the CR’s pods

Tags: operator-sdk

Reading this documentation

https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/building-operators/helm/tutorial/#overview

I cannot understand how can i achieve this goal with a helm-based operator.

I have only found solution with ansible-based and Go-based operators.